# Determine if a graph is semi-connected or not

Tags: algorithm, graph

A directed graph G = (V, E) is said to be semi-connected if, for all pairs of vertices u, v in V we have u -> v or v-> u path.
Give an efficient algorithm to determine whether or not G is semi-connected

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Trivial `O(V^3)` solution could be to use [floyd warshal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) all-to-all shortest path, but that's an overkill (in terms of time complexity).

It can be done in `O(V+E)`.

**Claim:**

A DAG is semi connected in a topological sort, for each `i`, there there is an edge `(vi,vi+1)`

**Proof:**

Given a DAG with topological sort `v1,v2,...,vn`:

If there is no edge `(vi,v(i+1))` for some `i`, then there is also no path `(v(i+1),vi)` (because it's a topological sort of a DAG), and the graph is not semi connected.

If for every `i` there is an edge `(vi,vi+1)`, then for each `i,j` (i < j) there is a path `vi->vi+1->...->vj-1->vj`, and the graph is semi connected.

From this we can get the algorithm:

1. Find Maximal SCCs in the graph.
2. Build the SCC graph G'=(U,E') such that `U` is a set of SCCs. `E'= { (V1,V2) | there is v1 in V1 and v2 in V2 such that (v1,v2) is in E }`.
3. Do topological sort on G'.
4. Check if for every i, there is edge Vi,V(i+1).

Correctness proof:

If the graph is semi connected, for a pair `(v1,v2)`, such that there is a path `v1->...->v2` - Let V1, V2 be their SCCs. There is a path from V1 to V2, and thus also from v1 to v2, since all nodes in V1 and V2 are strongly connected.

If the algorithm yielded true, then for any two given nodes v1, v2 - we know they are in SCC V1 and V2. There is a path from V1 to V2 (without loss of generality), and thus also from v1 to v2.

---

As a side note, also every semi-connected graph has a root (vertex `r` that leads to all vertices):

Proof:

Assume there is no root. Define `#(v) = |{u |  there is a path from v to u}|` (number of nodes that has a path from `v` to them).

Choose `a` such that `#(a) = max{#(v) | for all v}`.

`a` is not a root, so there is some node `u` that has no path from `a` to it. Since graph is semi connected, it means there is a path `u->...->a`. But that means `#(u) >= #(a) + 1` (all nodes reachable from `a` and also `u`).

Contradiction to maximality of `#(a)`, thus there is a root.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: what about if the graph is cyclic? in that case, there isn't a topological sort for it, but AFAICS it could still be semi-connected.

Comment: @PeriataBreatta As the answer says, you first take the SCCs (Strongly connected Components) The graph of SCCs (as described in 2) is guaranteed to be a DAG.

Comment: Is there a visual for this and what does maximal SCC mean?

Comment: @mLstudent33 SCC is Strongly Connected Components.

Comment: maximal is highest number?  So I'm guessing it's a sink SCC

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component

Answer (score 1):

Amit's soltuin described completely the most efficient approach. I might just add that one can replace step 4 by checking whether there exists more than one topological order of G'. If yes, then the graph is not semi connected. Otherwise, the graph is semi connected. This can be easily incorporated in [Kahn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn.27s_algorithm) for finding topological order of a graph.

Another less efficient solution that works in quadratic time is the following.

First, construct another graph G* which is the reverse of the original graph. Then for each vertex v of G, you run a DFS from v in G and consider the set of reachable nodes as R_v. If R_v != V(G), then run another DFS from v in G* and let the set of reachable nodes be R*_v. If the union of R_v and R*_v is not V(G) then the graph is not semi connected.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea behind step 3 and 4 of Amit's algorithms is to check whether your depth-first forest is comprised of multiple depth-first trees. Presence of a single tree is a necessary condition for semi-connectivity as multiple trees represent unconnected nodes.

Similar ideas: Hamiltonian path, Longest path length