# Is there a way to turn a DCG to a DAG without losing any connections?

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, cyclic

Im currently working on a homework problem that asks us to write an algorithm that checks if a directed cyclic graph is semi connected or not. My current thought process is (if possible) turn DCG to DAG to Topological. I’m stuck on whether or not it’s possible to turn a DCG to DAG without losing any connections. Everything I’ve come up with causes a connection to be lost.

Comment: What do you mean by 'without losing any connections'? Do you mean that the only operation you have is reversing the direction of arcs, or do you mean that if there's a directed path from A to B in the original graph, there must be a directed path from A to B in the resulting graph? or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine if a graph is semi-connected or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642383/determine-if-a-graph-is-semi-connected-or-not)

Comment: *"write an algorithm that checks if a directed cyclic graph is semi connected or not."* <<< Are you sure you meant "cyclic graph"? I don't know any standard definition of "cyclic graph". It might means "a graph that contains a cycle", or perhaps "a graph that is exactly a cycle", or perhaps "a graph that contains a cycle that covers all its vertices". Which one is it? Or perhaps you meant ***acyclic*** and not cyclic?

Comment: *"Everything I’ve come up with causes a connection to be lost."* <<< Can you give an example, with a graph on which you've tried something, and show which connection was lost and how?

Comment: Also, it looks like one of the purposes of this homework is to help you familiarise with the notion of semiconnected graph. Can you include the definition that you know for a semiconnected graph?

Comment: @Stef directed graph G = (V,E) is semiconnected if, for all pairs of vertices u, v ε V , there is a path from u to v or from v to u.

Comment: @Dave and Stef:  for example a graph with A, B, C vertices where A is connected to B, B is connected to C, A is connected to B. If I run dfs on it and removed the first edge that repeated, I would be left with a graph that has A, B, C vertices but a connection that was lost (A is no longer connected to B). Hopefully my thought process is making sense, sorry.

Comment: @Moronis2234 Oh yeah. Well, congratulations, you have proven that the task was impossible. There exist directed graph that are semiconnected and such that it is impossible to turn obtain an acyclic semiconnected graph just by removing edges.

Comment: But your original task, *"check if a directed cyclic graph is semi connected or not"*, is completely possible :-)

Comment: At the very least you can write a bruteforce algorithm: for every pair of vertices u, v, check whether there is a path from u to v or from v to u. And then when you have done that, you can think about making a more efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the graph consists of n nodes. You will run Dijkstra's algorithm n times, once for each node as the source. Then you will check for every pair of nodes x, y if either path x->y or path y->x exists. If you find at least one pair where this is not true, the graph is not semi-connected. Otherwise, it is.